# How do I feed a 2-dimensional array into a kernel with pycuda?

Tags: pycuda

I have created a numpy array of float32s with shape `(64, 128)`, and I want to send it to the GPU. How do I do that? What arguments should my kernel function accept? `float** myArray`?

I have tried directly sending the array as it is to the GPU, but pycuda complains that objects are being accessed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two dimensional arrays in numpy/PyCUDA are stored in pitched linear memory in row major order by default. So you only need to have a kernel something like this:

```
__global__
void kernel(float* a, int lda, ...)
{
    int r0 = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    int r1 = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    float val = a[r0 + r1*lda];

    ....
}
```

to access a numpy `ndarray` or PyCUDA `gpuarray` passed by reference to the kernel from Python.