# PyCuda program keeps on running

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, pycharm, anaconda, pycuda

```
  answer_array = np.zeros_like(self.redarray)
        answer_array_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(answer_array.nbytes)
        redarray_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(self.redcont.nbytes)
        greenarray_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(self.greencont.nbytes)
        bluearray_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(self.bluecont.nbytes)
        cuda.memcpy_htod(redarray_gpu, self.redcont)
        cuda.memcpy_htod(greenarray_gpu, self.greencont)
        cuda.memcpy_htod(bluearray_gpu, self.bluecont)
        cuda.memcpy_htod(answer_array_gpu, answer_array)

        desaturate_mod = SourceModule("""
            __global__ void array_desaturation(float *a, float *b, float *c, float *d){
                int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                d[index] = ((a[index] + b[index] + c[index])/3);
            }
        """)

        func = desaturate_mod.get_function("array_desaturation")
        func(redarray_gpu, greenarray_gpu, bluearray_gpu, answer_array_gpu,
             block=(self.gpu_threads, self.gpu_threads, self.blocks_to_use))
        desaturated = np.empty_like(self.redarray)
        cuda.memcpy_dtoh(desaturated, answer_array_gpu)
        print(desaturated)
        print("Up to here")
```

I wrote this piece of code for finding the average of values on three arrays and save it in to a fourth array. The code is neither printing the result, nor the line saying "Up to here". What could be the error?

Additional info: Redarray, greenarray and bluearray are float32 numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

I know getting started with arrays in C, and especially in PyCUDA can be pretty tricky, it took me months to get a 2D sliding max algorithm working.

In this example, you can't access array elements like you can in Python where you can just provide an index since you are passing a pointer to the memory address to the first element in each array. A useful example for how this works in C can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm). You will also have to pass in the length for the arrays (assuming they are all equal so that we do not go out of bounds) and if they are of different lengths, all of them respectively.

Hopefully, you can understand how to access your array elements via pointers in C from that link. Then @talonmies provides an nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850836/how-do-i-pass-a-2-dimensional-array-into-a-kernel-in-pycuda) for how to pass in a 2D array (this is the same as a 1D array since the 2D array gets flattened to a 1D one in memory on the GPU). However, when I was working with this, I never passed in the strides which @talonmies does, working like the TutorialsPoint tutorial says `*(pointer_to_array + index)` is correct. Providing a memory stride here will cause you to go out of bounds.

Therefore my code for this would look more like:

```
C_Code = """
            __global__ void array_desaturation(float *array_A, float *array_B, float *array_C, float *outputArray, int arrayLengths){
                int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
                if(index >= arrayLengths){ // In case our threads created would be outwise out of the bounds for our memory, if we did we would have some serious unpredictable problems
                    return;
                }

                // These variables will get the correct values from the arrays at the appropriate index relative to their unique memory addresses (You could leave this part out but I like the legibility)
                float aValue = *(array_A + index);
                float bValue = *(array_B + index);
                float cValue = *(array_C + index);

                *(outputArray + index) = ((aValue + bValue + cValue)/3); //Set the (output arrays's pointer + offset)'s value to our average value
                }"""


desaturate_mod = SourceModule(C_Code)
desaturate_kernel = desaturate_mod.get_function("array_desaturation")

desaturate_kernel(cuda.In(array_A),                    # Input
                  cuda.In(array_B),                    # Input
                  cuda.In(array_C),                    # Input
                  cuda.Out(outputArray),               # Output
                  numpy.int32(len(array_A)),           # Array Size if they are all the same length
                  block=(blockSize[0],blockSize[1],1), # However you want for the next to parameters but change your index accordingly
                  grid=(gridSize[0],gridSize[1],1)
                  )

print(outputArray) # Done! Make sure you have defined all these arrays before ofc
```